# selecting dropdown from given code

Tags: java, selenium

```
        ele = ConfigPage_POF.IVP3_Protocol_drpdwnbtn;
        act.moveToElement(ele);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        act.build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ele.click();
        Thread.sleep(500);[enter image description here][1]
```

i am new in automation testing.i am using selenium tool..i have a problem in selecting info from dropdown buttons.i am using this code but at some dropdowns it failing at click..is there any other way to select my dropdown succesfully.i am saving ID in ele=config_Protocol[this is my source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FoFB.png) _drpdwnbtn;
please help me.
thanks

Comment: can you share you html  code?

Comment: yes please click on the last line

Comment: what value is there in ConfigPage_POF.IVP3_Protocol_drpdwnbtn?

Comment: vs_in_protocol_vport2  this is id of that dropdown from html

Comment: please check my answer. it may help you. it will just click on it. you may have to write the code to select the option.

Comment: Paste the complete code with error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code may works.

```
ele = ConfigPage_POF.IVP3_Protocol_drpdwnbtn;
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.id(ele));
act.moveToElement(element).click(element).perform();
```

Comment: error on driver=driver cannot be resolved
error on id=the method id id stringin the type by is not applicable for argument webelement

Comment: which browser are you using? and how are you launching it?

Comment: chrome and eclipse
selinium and testNG

Comment: change the driver with your driver instance name.

Comment: i have changed .driver working fine  but id still have same error

Comment: :) Please share the URL

Comment: the driver variable have to be resolved by yourself. we couldn't help you without it.